# Integral of step function with a removable discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is a question about conventions.

If a step function $s(x)$ is defined on $[0,2]$:

> $s(x)=0 \ \ \ \forall x\neq 1$
>
> $s(1)=1$

Would you say it's integral on $[0,2]$ is $0$?
Is a singlepoint interval in partition P considered acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the integral is zero. If you go through the Riemann dance of divisions of the interval, and take the sum of (length of interval) times (maximal value in the interval) (respective minimal value), the supremum will be the length of the interval around 0, and that tends to 0 as the maximal length tends to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this integral evaluates to $0$. Here's an informal proof: a rectangle drawn from the point to the axis has height $1$, and width $0$ (the width of a single point is nothing), so its area is zero, and it has no contribution for the integral.

More formally, note that a finite amount of (bounded) discontinuities does not affect that a function is Riemann  integrability. Every closed function over a closed interval is Riemann integrable over the interval.